# How to keep low frequencies in DCT

Tags: lowpass-filter, transform, dct

How can I keep a percentage r of the low frequencies of a Nx1 signal x using the Discrete Cosine Transform of it? Is it simply zeroing all but the first rN elements of DCT(x)?

Comment: Pls share your frustrations with more details

Comment: Say I have a 16000x1 audio signal and I get it's 16000x1 DCT.
How can I enforce a signal at the range of frequencies 0-4kHz working in the frequency domain?
Is it just allowing non-zero values to the first 4000 elements of the DCT?

Comment: no that is not how it works , keep reading

Comment: could you please point me to a good reference for this?

Answer (score 0):

What I've understood is that k-th DCT-II component is expressed in a basis of cosine functions with frequency $k\pi/(2N)$ rads, where $N$ is the number of samples of the signal. Thus k-th coefficient of such a signal has frequency of $k/(2N)$ in Hz. It seems to me that my understanding is wrong because this constains highest frequency to $(N-1)/(2N)$.